# Ubuntu is randomly crashing into a static screen

Tags: 14.04, crash

This has happened a few times over the past few days, however, I have no idea what to troubleshoot or how to fix it.

Ubuntu will randomly crash into a 'static' screen, I took a picture on my phone, it looks like this:

[image]

I usually don't receive any error prompts after rebooting, either, other than a prompt advising me to report the error without listing details. How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

I received this error log when I booted my PC this morning. Seeing as this a graphical glitch for my open-source X.Org AMD driver, I thought that it may also be the cause for the crashing too:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Here's my PC specs: (this should help solve the problem)**

- GPU: MSI Radeon R9 280X w/ X.Org open-source driver
- CPU: Intel i5 4670K
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance 2x4GB
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS w/ all latest updates installed on OS & software
- Display Manager: Unity

Comment: I've been getting this too, did you ever get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Did you try the memory test, at boot menu?  Other test, create a new user and verify if happens the frozen screen. Other checklist, verify the last event before a crash on /var/logs.

Comment: Sorry, this was ages ago. IIRC I just ended up reinstalling the OS, and I can't remember what happened